# After the destruction of the object, the object is still available. rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-rails

After the destruction of the object, the object is still available. 
I have a conventional method in the controller in which the object is destroyed.

```
def destroy
  authorize @object, :update?

  @attachment.destroy
  redirect_to polymorphic_path(@object), notice: 'Attachment deleted!'
end
```

The problem with the testing.

```
describe AttachmentsController do
  before do
    create_account_and_login
    @ticket = FactoryGirl.create(:ticket, account: @account)
    @attachment = FactoryGirl.build(:attachment, object: @ticket)
  end

  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  describe '#destroy' do
    it 'destroys the attachment' do
      VCR.use_cassette_with_file 'save sailormoon.jpg and delete and check existance' do
        @attachment.save!

        expect {
          delete :destroy, params: {id: @attachment.id, ticket_id: @ticket.id}
        }.to change { @ticket.attachments.count }.by(-1)

        expect(S3_BUCKET.object(@attachment.key).exists?).to be_falsey
      end

      expect(flash[:notice]).to be_present
      expect(response).to redirect_to(ticket_path(@ticket))
    end
  end
end
```

Nothing usual, but.
`delete :destroy, params: {id: @attachment.id, ticket_id: @ticket.id}`
The called method of destruction.
The object is removed, all is well. I checked with `@attachment.destroyed?`
And got `true`.
But the object is still available.
`@attachment.key` returned the key. Why?
This behavior appeared after upgrading to rails 4 to 5.

Comment: The @attachment object  should be deleted from the database but you have an in memory copy that was created before you deleted it and so you can still work with it. If you were to do something like `@attachment.reload` you should get a not found exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is as follows. Аile deletion is S3 is done through a job, so add `perform_enqueued_jobs` around that controller call.

```
describe '#destroy' do
  it 'destroys the attachment' do
    VCR.use_cassette_with_file 'save sailormoon.jpg and delete and check existance' do
      @attachment.save!

      expect {
        perform_enqueued_jobs { delete :destroy, params: {id: @attachment.id, ticket_id: @ticket.id} }
      }.to change { @ticket.attachments.count }.by(-1)

      expect(S3_BUCKET.object(@attachment.key).exists?).to be_falsey
    end

    expect(flash[:notice]).to be_present
    expect(response).to redirect_to(ticket_path(@ticket))
  end
end
```